# Why doesn't if any(var0) == any(var1) work?

Tags: python

I'm very new to programming, and more new to Python, and I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I'm trying to make a simple text hangman game, and I'm trying to validate player1's input. Here's what I have so far.

```
a = 0

int = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

while a == 0:
    print("Please choose any word by typing it here:")
    d = input()
    d = list(d)
    print(d)
    if any(int) == any(d):
        print("Invalid input. Please choose a non-number with no spaces or special characters.")
```

I can't figure why, whether I include a number in my response or not, it always meets my any(int) == any(d) condition. I know I must just be misunderstanding how any() works.

Comment: Just in case, `int` is a special word, be careful!

Comment: The `any` function returns a boolean.  These two `any` calls are not related in any way. 
 In this case, both `any` calls return True, which makes them equal.  What you wanted is `if any(k in int for k in d):`

Comment: And, by the way, a list of single characters is easier to type as a string:  `ints = "1234567890"`.  Strings can be iterated just like lists.

Comment: Don't forget to change the value of `a`, or the loop will never terminate. `while True`: with an explicit `break` statement would be cleaner than introducing an otherwise unnecessary flag variable.

Comment: @TimRoberts And in this case one doesn't even have to define it since [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits) can be used.

Comment: @zarquon
Thanks so much! This makes sense - I've reformatted to

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are right: the issue is with how you use the `any()` function. `any()` returns either `True` or `False` depending on whether or not any of the elements in its iterable argument are `True`, in other words if they exist and are not `False` or an empty list or empty string or 0. This will always evaluate as `True` for `int` because `int` does contain an element that is `True` and the same will happen for `d` unless you do not give any input when the `input()` function prompts you (you hit return without typing anything). What your conditional is basically asking is the following:

```
if True==True
```

To fix this, just change your code to the following:

```
a = 0

int = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

while a == 0:
    print("Please choose any word by typing it here:")
    d = input()
    print(d)
    for letter in d:
        if letter in int:
            print("Invalid input. Please choose a non-number with no spaces or special characters.")
            break
```

The easiest solution, however, does not involve the `int` list at all. There is actually a special method in python that can gauge whether or not a string has a number (or special character) in it, and this method, `.isalpha()` can be used to streamline this process even further. Here's how to implement this solution:

```
while True:
    d = input("Please choose any word by typing it here: \n")
    print(d)
    if not d.isalpha():
        print("Invalid input. Please choose a non-number with no spaces or special characters.")
```

Comment: This will print the error message way more times than is necessary.

Comment: Yep, that should do it!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
a = 0

ints = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

while a == 0:
    print("Please choose any word by typing it here:")
    word = input()
    word_list = list(word)
    if any(letter in ints for letter in word_list):
        print("Invalid input. Please choose a non-number with no spaces or special characters.")
```

Comment: Why? Can you explain?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a list comprehension here - it is just an unnecessarily complicated version of in for this case.

Comment: `any` returns a boolean that is `True` if any of the conditions in the parameter passed to it are `True`. The code checks to see if any "letter" in the input is in `ints`. If so, the input is invalid, and the message is printed.

Comment: @linger1109 then what would you recommend?

Comment: Look at my post -- if you use the `in` keyword, it will check if a value is anywhere within a list, which just does the same thing as here but simpler.

Comment: @linger1109 you need to use a comprehension of some sort. the idea is to check each letter, not just the full word.

Comment: Ah -- my fault, I misinterpreted.

Comment: Ha, I made that same misinterpretation in my original answer!